# EmberJS: how to send an action from a controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a modal dialog, which is implemented similar to what is described in the cookbook: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

I can close the modal without any problems via an event from the template. However, I have implemented a controller for the specific modal which creates a new model with the data that has been entered via the modal. Now I want to close the dialog after the model (after the controller is done) has been created. I tried various ways to send an action from a controller to the modal, however nothing worked so far. So, two questions:

- How do I close the modal when the action in the controller is done?

  ```
  export default ModalController.extend({
    actions: {
      create: function() {
      // do some stuff
      var newModel = this.store.createRecord('newModel', {
          name: name
      });
      newModel.save()
      // close modal
      // ... but how?
  }
  ```
- As this relies on promises, I think this would close the modal after the promise is created. How do I close the modal when the actual response from the server arrives and everything went fine?

Comment: Assuming you already have a `closeModal` action for when to user closes the modal, to close the modal you can use the `Em.TargetActionSupport` mixin's `triggerAction()` method to set `action: 'closeModal', target: this` or something along those lines using the methos bguiz suggested. [More info here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TargetActionSupport.html#method_triggerAction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ember Data for your models:

```
export default ModalController.extend({
  actions: {
    create: function() {
    // do some stuff
    var newModel = this.store.createRecord('newModel', {
        name: name
    });
    newModel.save().then(function success() {
        //success message and close modal
    }).catch(function failure() {
        //error message and close modal
    });
}
```

The basic idea here is to register `success` and `failure` callbacks for `Model.save()`,
and close the modal dialog within those callbacks.

As for how to actually close the modal dialog, assuming that you have the implementation of
`closeModal` within the actions hash of this same `Controller`,
you need to invoke the action by name, through `this.send()`

```
    newModel.save().then(function success() {
        //success message and close modal
        this.send('closeModal');
    }.bind(this)) /* ... */
```

Be sure to call `.bind()` on the callback functions, so that `this` refers to what you would expect it to (the controller).
I recall [asking a question about just this a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18743760/194982).

HTH!